# Proving formally

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

$((\exists x : X.P) \Rightarrow (\forall x: X.Q)) \vdash (\forall x: X. PvQ) \Rightarrow((\forall x: X.P) \vee(\forall x: X. Q)$

exist stands for the existential quantifier
all stands for for-all quantifier in discrete maths

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $((\exists x.P) \implies (\forall x.Q))$ and $(\forall x. P\vee Q)$, we want to deduce the last part.
It suffices to write the following chain of deduction.

$\begin{array}{l}
(\forall x. P\vee Q)\text{ (second axiom)}\\
(\forall x. Q)\vee (\exists x.P)\text{ (case disjunction)}\\
(\forall x. Q) \vee (\forall x.Q)\text{ (using first axiom)}\\
(\forall x. Q)\\
(\forall x. P)\vee(\forall x. Q)\text{ ($\vee$-introduction).}
\end{array}$

So you can in fact prove something stronger, we always have $(\forall x. Q)$ if the assumptions are verified.